# Android app crashes when button is clicked (this happens probably due to the ListView thing i've added)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

my app says gives me a pop up saying that OMG Android has stopped when I click the one and only button in my app. This is probably due to the ListView Component I have used which stores the stuff I enter in the EditText component. I'm a beginner . Please Help! (I use a kitkat phone to try this app out using file C:\Users\admin\AndroidStudioProjects\OMGAndroid\app\build\outputs\apk)

activity_main.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/main_textview"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/main_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <!-- Set OnClickListener to trigger results when pressed -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/button" />
    <!-- Shows an image from your drawable resources -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <!-- Closing tag for the horizontal nested layout -->
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Displays keyboard when touched -->
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/main_edittext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:hint="@string/hint" />
```

MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.admin.omgandroid ;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements   View.OnClickListener {

TextView mainTextView;
Button mainButton;
EditText mainEditText;
ListView mainListView;
ArrayAdapter mArrayAdapter;
ArrayList mNameList = new ArrayList();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // 1. Access the TextView defined in layout XML
    // and then set its text
    mainTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_textview);
    mainTextView.setText("Set in Java!");
    // 2. Access the Button defined in layout XML
    // and listen for it here
    mainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_button);
    mainButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mainEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_edittext);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    mainTextView.setText("Button Pressed");
    mainTextView.setText(mainEditText.getText().toString() + " is learning android development");
    // Also add that value to the list shown in the ListView
    mNameList.add(mainEditText.getText().toString());
    mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.admin.omgandroid" >
<uses-sdk
    android:targetSdkVersion="21"
    android:minSdkVersion="16" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

strings.xml :

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">OMG Android</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">As if</string>
<string name="button">Update The TextView</string>
<string name="hint">A Name</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Where is your error log

Comment: And where is your list view ??

Comment: It's in activity_main.xml and MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

This is a part of your code

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    mainTextView.setText("Button Pressed");
    mainTextView.setText(mainEditText.getText().toString() + " is learning android development");
    // Also add that value to the list shown in the ListView
    mNameList.add(mainEditText.getText().toString());

    //This is where you are going wrong
    mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Where have you initialized your array adapter, where is array adapter object?

How your listview is getting data?

This is what you should do

- Initialize your array adapter
- Get the reference of the list view item.
- Set adapter to the listview

No need to do **notifydatasetChange** here

Create one more layout, for the adapter to create a view.
In your case, since it is just a text, create a layout with TextView as it's child.

let's say this layout name is listView_text_layout

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_text_view"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
</TextView>
```

Now, add this code

```
 mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.listView_text_layout,R.id.list_item_text_view,mNameList);
            ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_listview);
            listView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
```

I also recommend to see the developer guide for using arrayadapter or some tutorials.

Comment: Can I initialize it to null ?

Comment: I'm a beginner so if you would please add the code for doing the following ;

Comment: Initialize your array adapter
Get the reference of the list view item.
Set adapter to the listview

Comment: yes, you can set to null. But, again the compiler will throw null pointer exception at runTime.

Comment: I have added the code,add it after mNameList.add(mainEditText.getText().toString());

Answer (score 0):

Edit my answer

At begin of class

```
ArrayAdapter <String>mArrayAdapter; 
ArrayList<String> mNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

At end of onCreate:

```
mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mNameList);
mainListView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: This answer wont answer the question..please delete the answer and add it as a comment instead..

Comment: I just run the app on my phone and when I press the button a thing pops up and says OMG Android has stopped

Comment: the answer is that he don't initialize the adapter

Comment: can you like tell me where should I make changes in the code above ?